# Where can I buy Salsify in the UK?

Tags: resources, shopping

I like the look and taste of salsify, and have had it in restaurants.  However, I cannot find anywhere to buy it.  I don't even mind how it comes - tinned, frozen, fresh.

Answer (score 3):

Where did you look?
Here in Belgium we can find in the supermarket (in cans or frozen). We also have it fresh on some markets.

Maybe [this](http://www.efoodies.co.uk/invt/salsify/) can help you.
[Here](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=814710) is a similar thread.

If you really can't find it, you can always buy seeds and put them in your garden.

Comment: Growing my own is a very good idea which I hadn't thought about.

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly sure I have seen it in Waitrose, when I had one close by - not sure if they still stock  it, or if it is location dependant. They don't appear to have it via Ocado either.
Need to be quick though - it's the back end of the season already.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds obvious, but just in case -- you should ask at your local greengrocer. They will at least learn that there's a demand, and try it for one order.

Specialised greengrocers often have more interesting stuff than supermarkets -- I've seen romanesque a lot at my local one, and never in a supermarket.

You could also ask the restaurant where you tasted it, where they bought it.

Answer (score 0):

You can order it online. I don't personally know of any shops where you cab physically go to buy it though.

Answer (score 0):

Fresh salsify is usually only sold in supermarkets when in season. For Europe, this is mainly the autumn and winter months.